# CSS Inheritance not working as expected

Tags: html, css, inheritance, stylesheet

So I have html and css that looks like the following..

```
    <div id="foo">
        <p> Foo text </p>
        <div id="bar">
            <p> Bar text </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And then I have some css that looks like the following...

```
    #foo p {
    text-align:left;
    font-family: helvetica, verdana, sans;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    #bar p {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```

So isn't the point of CSS to override the styles applied to the child from the parent foo? It's not doing this, I just get the child styles overridden by the parent. I'm clearly missing something big here, any help would be great.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood your question, it seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/sYMdR/

Comment: What is your problem specifically? Padding, color and font-size must definitely be different in #bar p. is this what is not working?

Comment: if you expect other styles (i.e. margin, font-family, etc.) to be reset as well you are wrong, you need to say: margin:inherit for that

Comment: Yeah, can you clarify what is not working as expected?

Comment: It works fine, maybe you have a syntax error preventing the parsing of the additional styles.  I would advise downloading firefox with firebug if you don't have them already.

Comment: Overriding of rules in CSS has nothing to do with parent/child element relationships.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confused, or have coded yourself blind. :) What you have works perfectly well, it is your intentions that I suspect is off. What you're thinking is that the first set of styles should be inherited and then overwritten by the second, but if you look to your HTML, that's not the structure you've put in place.

You're saying `#foo's` `<p>'s` should have the first style, but the second set of styles are in a `<div>`, and hence *not* applied. The second p is in a `<div>`, and hence will not have the first rules which are for elements under a `<p>`.

If you want the styles to inherit, wrap your `<div>` *into* your `<p>` (even though structurally not good, nor valid in a number of schemas);

```
<div id="foo">
        <p> Foo text 
        <div id="bar">
            <p> Bar text </p>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, though, so it's a bit hard to come up with good examples to solve your problem. :)

Comment: I totally can't understand what you're aiming for but we don't know what he mean either :) I will keep an eye on the conversation!

Answer (score -1):

Look Chris you're misunderstanding CSS selectors and their inheritance ...

Nothing will explain it better than this presentation by [Russ Weakly](http://maxdesign.com.au)

[CSS Cascade](http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/css-cascade-1658158)